# "Generic parameter could not be inferred" in SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I've got the following code, which makes it possible to use the UIKit's `UIScrollView` in my SwiftUI code. It can be pasted in a new SwiftUI project.

```
struct LegacyScrollView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    enum Action {
        case idle
        case offset(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, animated: Bool)
    }

    @Binding var action: Action
    let content: Content

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: self.content)
        hosting.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let uiScrollView = UIScrollView()
        uiScrollView.addSubview(hosting.view)

        let constraints = [
            hosting.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.leadingAnchor),
            hosting.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.trailingAnchor),
            hosting.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            hosting.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            hosting.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.widthAnchor)
        ]
        uiScrollView.addConstraints(constraints)

        return uiScrollView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        switch self.action {
        case .offset(let x, let y, let animated):
            uiView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: y), animated: animated)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.action = .idle
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        let legacyScrollView: LegacyScrollView

        init(_ legacyScrollView: LegacyScrollView) {
            self.legacyScrollView = legacyScrollView
        }
    }

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self._action = Binding.constant(Action.idle)
        self.content = content()
    }

    init(action: Binding<Action>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self._action = action
        self.content = content()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var action = LegacyScrollView.Action.idle

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            LegacyScrollView(action: self.$action) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 40) { _ in
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
            }
            .padding(20)
            .background(Color.gray)
            Spacer()
            Button("Set offset") {
                self.action = LegacyScrollView.Action.offset(x: 0, y: 200, animated: true)
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will give `Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred` on the first line of the `ContentView`. I've tried to change the line to:

```
@State private var action = LegacyScrollView<AnyView>.Action.idle
```

but that will give another error. It works when I place the `enum Action` outside the `struct LegacyScrollView`. But in my opinion, that's a rather inelegant scoping of this enum. How can I solve the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is possible approach that allows usage of provided `ContentView` as-is.

Just change the direction of... instead of making entire type generic, which is actually not needed in this case, just make a generic only initialisation, like below.

Also it actually makes clear that `Action` is Content-independent, that is really correct.

Tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2 (w/o no changes in `ContentView`)

```
struct LegacyScrollView: UIViewRepresentable {
    enum Action {
        case idle
        case offset(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, animated: Bool)
    }

    @Binding var action: Action
    private let uiScrollView: UIScrollView

    init<Content: View>(content: Content) {
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
        hosting.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        uiScrollView = UIScrollView()
        uiScrollView.addSubview(hosting.view)

        let constraints = [
            hosting.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.leadingAnchor),
            hosting.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.trailingAnchor),
            hosting.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            hosting.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            hosting.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiScrollView.widthAnchor)
        ]
        uiScrollView.addConstraints(constraints)

        self._action = Binding.constant(Action.idle)
    }

    init<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.init(content: content())
    }

    init<Content: View>(action: Binding<Action>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.init(content: content())
        self._action = action
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        return uiScrollView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        switch self.action {
        case .offset(let x, let y, let animated):
            uiView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: y), animated: animated)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.action = .idle
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        let legacyScrollView: LegacyScrollView

        init(_ legacyScrollView: LegacyScrollView) {
            self.legacyScrollView = legacyScrollView
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify this piece of code to support dynamic content from the forEach-loop and if yes, how could it be done?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean "support dynamic content from the forEach-loop" using `UIScrollView` with `UIViewRepresentable `. I guess that's a no.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with your assertion that the `enum` should be nested inside the class  for the following reasons:

- The `enum` is intended to be used both inside and outside of the class, with a generic type being required in order to use it.
- The `enum` does not make use of, and therefore has no dependency on, the generic `Content` type.
- With a good enough name, the intended use of the `enum` would be obvious.

---

If you *really want* to nest the `enum` definition, I would suggest the following:

- Drop the generic type requirement on the class definition,
- Convert your `content` member to be of `AnyView` type,
- Make your `init` functions generic and store the return values of the given view builders into type-erased views, like so:

```
init<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self._action = Binding.constant(Action.idle)
    self.content = AnyView(content())
}

init<Content: View>(action: Binding<Action>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self._action = action
    self.content = AnyView(content())
}
```

Of course, with this approach, you will:

- Lose the type information of the underlying content view.
- Possibly incur a greater runtime cost with type-erased views.

So it depends what you value more in this case... Ahhh, tradeoffs...