# How to wrap a horizontal UIScrollView so it works for SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI, I need to use a horizontal UIScrollView in an SwiftUI app, but I can't manage to get it to render the views properly when I tried to wrap it. The views I put inside just disappear. Is there a way to fix a wrapped UIScrollView to Horizontal scroll only?

Here is my attempt.

```
struct CustomScrollView<Content>: UIViewRepresentable where Content : View {
    let content: () -> Content

    init(proxy: ListScrollingProxy, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content

    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
         let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
               let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
               let size = hosting.view.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
               hosting.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: size.height)
               let scrollview = UIScrollView()


                scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
                scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

               scrollview.addSubview(hosting.view)
               scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: size.height)

               return scrollview
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {

       }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60168697/12299030) you can find already solved integration of UIScrollView for vertical scrolling, so you need only configure it properly for horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the view I'm wrapping contains a WKWebView. So I turn off scrolling since the SwiftUI view handles the scrolling:

```
wrappedView.webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Also, you'll need to make sure that your view returns the correct `intrinsicContentSize` value - the full size of the view so no scrolling is required.