# ambiguous type name 'Coordinator' in 'MyViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct MyViewController<Content:View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let content:Content
    @Binding var text :String
    init(text:Binding<String>,@ViewBuilder content : () -> Content){
        self.content = content()
        self._text = text
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
             Coordinator(self)
    }
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        let sc = UIScrollView()
        let host = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
        vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        sc.backgroundColor = .red
        sc.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 200)
        sc.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 2000)
        sc.addSubview(host.view)
        vc.view.addSubview(sc)
        sc.delegate = context.coordinator
        context.coordinator.host = host
        context.coordinator.scrollView = sc
        return vc
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
//        let scrollView = context.coordinator.scrollView!
//        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:1,y: 0), animated: true)
        let pageWidth : Int = 100
        let contentSize: CGSize = CGSize(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height:100)
        let scrollView = context.coordinator.scrollView!
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: Int(300),height: Int(contentSize.height))
           scrollView.contentSize = contentSize
           scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0 * Int(pageWidth),y: 0), animated: true)
           context.coordinator.host.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: contentSize)
    
        print("updateUIViewController")
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject,UIScrollViewDelegate {
      let parent: MyViewController
      var scrollView : UIScrollView!
      var host : UIHostingController<Content>!
      
      init(_ parent: MyViewController) {
          self.parent = parent
      }
      func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
          print("123")
      }
      func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
          print("end")
      }
  }
}

struct ContentView1 : View {
    @State var text: String = "1"
    var body: some View {
      MyViewController(text:$text){
                        VStack(alignment: .center){
                            Text("1")
                        }.frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 200) .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1) {
                                               self.text = "onLongPressGesture"
                            print("onTap")
                        }
                    }
    }
}
struct ContentView1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       ContentView1()
    }
}
```

Add any methods  to method of Coordinator.

Xcode throws the error:

> ambiguous type name 'Coordinator' in 'MyViewController'

Why does it throw the error? I don't understand.

The code here can be copied and run.

Comment: Could you be more precise which method and where did you add it and where/if did you call it? (because those I tried worked well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you encountered this problem when previewing. I had the same error. I think instead of making the entire `MyViewController` generic, just move the genericity to the initializer then the error will be gone (got the hint from [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60168697/8577754))

```
struct MyViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable
{
   let content: AnyView
   @Binding var text :String

   init<Content: View>(text:Binding<String>, @ViewBuilder content : () -> Content) {
      self.content = AnyView(content())
      self._text = text
   }
   ...

   class Coordinator: NSObject,UIScrollViewDelegate {
      ...
      var host : UIHostingController<AnyView>!

      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edited for clarification of the problem]

#### Issue

This is currently a bug when trying to view previews. It's because previews does code generation behind the scenes, and when it does it tries to generate a typealias to the coordinator class:

```
typealias Coordinator = MyViewController.Coordinator
```

This fails because `MyViewController` is a generic and needs to be specified as something `MyViewController<...>`.

Note: You can actually view the generated code if you're interested. Once the error appears, click on the **Diagnostics** button to get the file location.

#### Workaround

Move the `Coordinator` outside of the controller class.

To give your `Coordinator` access to the parent controller, you will need to implement a `protocol` abstraction. i.e. instead of referencing the controller directly, the coordinator will reference the protocol instead.

Example:

In my case, I was interfacing with UIKit. I needed the generic definition to be able to use a `UIPageViewController` subclass.

```
public struct PageView<P: UIPageViewController>: View {
    public var body: some View {
        Controller<P>()
    }
}

fileprivate struct Controller<P: UIPageViewController>: CoordinatorParent {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> P {
        return P(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: P, context: Context) {}
}

fileprivate protocol CoordinatorParent {
    // Any variables your coordinator needs access to    
}

fileprivate class Coordinator: NSObject {
    var parent: CoordinatorParent

    init(_ parent: CoordinatorParent) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class FooPageViewController: UIPageViewController {}

struct FooView: View {
    var body: some View {
        PageView<FooPageViewController>()
    }
}
```