# View content doesn't appear in UIScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this...

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
    
    let control = UIScrollView()
 
    control.addSubview(UIHostingController(rootView: preview).view)
 
    return control
}
```

If I put my `preview` view outside of my custom scroll view then I can see it. But when I add it as a subview of a `UIScrollView` then I can't see anything.

Have I added it correctly?

Here is the complete code for the scroll view, which I got from [here](https://www.appsdissected.com/missing-features-swiftui-uiviewrepresentable-wrap-uikit-controls/).

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct LegacyScrollView : UIViewRepresentable {
     
    var preview: AnyView
    
    init(preview: AnyView) {
        
        self.preview = preview
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        
        Coordinator(self)
    }
 
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        
        let control = UIScrollView()
 
        control.addSubview(UIHostingController(rootView: preview).view)
 
        return control
    }
 
 
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {

    }
 
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        
        var control: LegacyScrollView
 
        init(_ control: LegacyScrollView) {
            
            self.control = control
        }
 
        @objc func handleRefreshControl(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
 
            sender.endRefreshing()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There were many posts about UIScrollView integration in SwiftUI... try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61371933/12299030), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60168697/12299030), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62392498/12299030) ... find others in search.

Comment: I used this and it seems to work great... https://gist.github.com/jfuellert/67e91df63394d7c9b713419ed8e2beb7